# FindFirst,FindNext,FindClose

Tags: delphi

I want to make a new .txt file which parameters i load from a .script file. It works fine in the root. .script file is in the root directry.The result is:

> 1. 192.121.2.2 login Lucey password red
> 2. 192.321.2.1 login Steve password apple

.

```
  if FindFirst('*.*', faAnyFile, Search) = 0 then
  begin
    while FindNext(Search) = 0 do
    begin
      if FileExists(Search.Name) then
      begin
        if pos('.txt', Search.Name) <> 0 then
        begin
          Assignfile(txtfile, Search.Name);
          Erase(txtfile);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  findclose(Search);

  if FindFirst('*.*', faAnyFile, Search) = 0 then
  begin
    while FindNext(Search) = 0 do
    begin
      if FileExists(Search) then
      begin
        if pos('.script', Search.Name) <> 0 then
        begin
          data_file := TStringList.Create;
          data_file.LoadFromFile(Search.Name);
          txtdata := data_file.Strings[1].+ 'login' + data_file.Strings[2] +
            'password' + data_file.Strings[3];
          txtfile := TStringList.Create;
          if FileExists('.txt') then
          begin
            txtfile.LoadFromFile('.txt');
          end;
          txtfile.Add(txtdata);
          txtfile.SaveToFile('.txt');
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  findclose(Search);
```

But if i want to add C:\Script\Files the code i use is wrong, what is the problem? Pls help!

```
  if FindFirst('c:\Script\Files\*.*', faAnyFile, Search) = 0 then
  begin
    while FindNext(Search) = 0 do
    begin
      if FileExists(Search.Name) then
      begin
        if pos('c:\Script\Files\.txt', Search.Name) <> 0 then
        begin
          Assignfile(txtfile, Search.Name);
          Erase(txtfile);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  findclose(Search);

  if FindFirst('*.*', faAnyFile, Search) = 0 then
  begin
    while FindNext(Search) = 0 do
    begin
      if FileExists(Search) then
      begin
        if pos('.script', Search.Name) <> 0 then
        begin
          data_file := TStringList.Create;
          data_file.LoadFromFile(Search.Name);
          txtdata := data_file.Strings[1] + 'login' + data_file.Strings[2] +
            'password' + data_file.Strings[3];
          txtfile := TStringList.Create;
          if FileExists('c:\Script\Files\.txt') then
          begin
            txtfile.LoadFromFile('c:\Script\Files\.txt');
          end;
          txtfile.Add(txtdata);
          txtfile.SaveToFile('c:\Script\Files\.txt');
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  findclose(Search);
```

The result is:

> 1. 192.121.2.2 login Lucey password red
> 2. 192.121.2.2 login Lucey password red
> 3. 192.321.2.1 login Steve password apple

The 1st item shows twice etc.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. With a quick look, this line: `if pos('c:\Script\Files\.txt',..` needs to be correcting.

Comment: The statement I referred to is still remains, don't know if it's a *copy/paste* error but a TSearchRec.Name will hold a file name, you can't find a 'c:\Script\Files\.txt' in it.

Comment: Steve, why did you change the indentation of your code away from what I edited? It reduced readability. When you're asking people to help you, [you should make it *as easy as possible* for them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/11/06/10365956.aspx). That includes making your code easy to understand. Please don't inflict your quirky and inconsistent indentation style on everyone else. In fixing your mistakes, you introduced a new mistake, and your code also no longer matches the output you claim it generates.

Comment: @Steve88, I fixed the code formatting. If you have a modern Delphi (Delphi-2009 or newer), there is a built in code-formatter in the IDE. Just press <ctrl>+<D> for a short-cut or Edit|Format Source from the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite a lot of logic bugs in your code.  Try this instead:

```
if FindFirst('c:\Script\Files\*.txt',faAnyFile,Search) = 0 then
begin
  repeat
    DeleteFile('c:\Script\Files\' + Search.Name);
  until FindNext(Search) <> 0;
  FindClose(Search);
end;

txtfile := TStringList.Create;
try
  if FindFirst(PathToScriptFiles + '*.script',faAnyFile,Search) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      data_file := TStringList.Create;
      try
        data_file.LoadFromFile(PathToScriptFiles + Search.Name);
        txtdata := data_file.Strings[1] + ' login ' + data_file.Strings[2] + ' password ' + data_file.Strings[3];
        txtfile.Add(txtdata);
      finally
        data_file.Free;
      end;
    until FindNext(Search) <> 0;
    FindClose(Search);
  end;
  txtfile.SaveToFile('c:\Script\Files\.txt');
finally
  txtfile.Free;
end;
```

Comment: And sorry for the mistakes!I'm new in the "programming" world:) I will be watching for them